# How can I make my output return correctly for boards of all sizes?

Tags: python, list, function

So I'm trying to implement a function `contains_R(grid:List[str]) -> str` that takes a `grid` and returns the winner or - if no one has won.  Specifically, the given board `grid` will be a list of strings, where each string has length. There are two players R and G, so each position in the board  is either the string R or G if it has been occupied---or . (dot) for an unoccupied spot.  I'm trying to return the string R if the R player has won; the string G if the G player has won; or the string - otherwise.

**Each player will win only if their letter `R` or `G` appears 4 consecutive times regardless of the size of the board. The board is also guaranteed to be equal to or bigger than a 4*4 board**

So my code works fine in most circumstances.. here is my code btw

```
def portillo(board2):
    s = []
    for i in board2:
        s.append(list(i))
    return s
def rows(grid):
    r = list()
    for row in portillo(grid):
        r.append("".join(row))
    return r
def columns(grid):
    e = ''
    results = []
    for j in range(len(grid)):
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            e = e+grid[i][j]
        results.append(e)
        e = ''
    return results
def diagonalbottomleft_topright(grid):
      grid = portillo(grid)
      results = []
      for i in range(len(grid)):
        tmp1=""
        tmp2=""
        for j in range(0,len(grid)-i):
            tmp1+=grid[i+j][j]
            tmp2+=grid[j][i+j]
        results.append(tmp1)
        results.append(tmp2)
      return list(results)
def diagonal2topleft_bottomright(grid):
    results = []
    n=len(grid)
    for i in range(n):
        tmp1=""
        tmp2=""
        for j in range(i+1):
            tmp1+=grid[i-j][j]
            tmp2+=grid[n-1-j][n-1-i+j]
        results.append(tmp1)
        results.append(tmp2)
    return list(results)
def contains_R(grid):
    if 'RRRR' in diagonal1(grid):
        return 'R'
    if 'RRRR' in diagonal2(grid):
        return 'R'
    if 'RRRR' in rows(grid):
        return 'R'
    if 'RRRR' in columns(grid):
        return 'R'
    if 'GGGG' in diagonal1(grid):
        return 'G'
    if 'GGGG' in diagonal2(grid):
        return 'G'
    if 'GGGG' in rows(grid):
        return 'G'
    if 'GGGG' in columns(grid):
        return 'G'
    else:
        return '-'
```

However, when my code is bigger than a 4v4 board, like lets say I have a 6v6 board, and when `R or G` do appear 4 times in a row like this...

```
(contains_R([  '.GGGGR',
               'RGGRRG',
               'RR...R',
               'GR.GG.',
               '.G.RRG',
               'R.GGRG'])))
```

instead of returning `G` because it appears four times in a row in the first line, my code returns `-` instead...

So what changes should I make?

P.S.: I have added helper functions to find every possibilities of combinations, and the function name should provide the information for what direction it's checking for, its looking for every combination in a `row`, `column` and the `diagonals`

Comment: If the right side of "in" operator is a list, the operator only is true if there is an item in the list which is **equal** to string on the left side of "in".

Comment: Solution: Instead of a list create a large string where rows/columns/diagonals are separated by another character, e. g. `|`. Then you can check if e. g. "RRRR" is in it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank u for ur response.. but I'm not sure where do u want me to change my code, can you please edit or add the changes you described in my code??

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating it a little. Find all of the rows, columns, and diagonals, and return this as a list of lines. For each line you can check if "RRRR" or "GGGG" is in it.

For finding the lines, you can just combine your current logic into one function. Using a `defaultdict` here will also make the logic a bit easier:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_lines(grid):
    rows = defaultdict(str)
    cols = defaultdict(str)
    bdiag = defaultdict(str)
    fdiag = defaultdict(str)

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            v = grid[i][j]
            rows[i] += v
            cols[j] += v
            bdiag[i + j] += v
            fdiag[i - j] += v

    return [*rows.values(), *cols.values(), *bdiag.values(), *fdiag.values()]
```

Now the main method becomes a lot simpler:

```
def find_winner(grid):
    for line in find_lines(grid):
        if "RRRR" in line:
            return "R"
        if "GGGG" in line:
            return "G"
    return "-"
```